# Java 8 stream - filter on nested map and rebuild

Tags: java, java-8, nested, java-stream, treemap

I have a nested map in the form

```
TreeMap<LocalDate, Map<Long,TreeMap<BigDecimal,String>>>
```

and I have to process this map and end up with a map of the same structure where the nested TreeMap

```
TreeMap<BigDecimal, String>>
```

has exactly two elements.

I can find the elements I want with

```
values.entrySet().stream().flatMap(date -> date.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                             .map(type -> type.getValue().entrySet()))
                                             .filter(valueMap -> valueMap.size() == 2 )
```

but I can't work out how to express the .collect() to re-assemble the structure. Any pointers will be welcome.

Comment: So, in the innermost values, if there is a `TreeMap<BigDecimal, String>>` of *size not equal to `2`* you want to remove the complete entry from the outermost level? or from the second nested level? Anyway, this is a nice example of why the data structures defined by user are more appropriate than using just a nested `Map`s.

Answer (score 1):

You're losing information when calling `flatMap` and `map`. You  need to preserve keys in order to be able to rebuild your structure.

With a slight change, you can just filter the inner maps and collect them using an inner stream, without affecting the structure of the outer stream:

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<Long, TreeMap<BigDecimal, String>>> result = values.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> entry.getValue()
                           .entrySet()
                           .stream()
                           .filter(subEntry -> subEntry.getValue().size() == 2)
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                 Entry::getValue)))
                        );
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this would filter the entries at the second level of nesting and not from the complete(outer) map if that was the expectation.

Comment: @Naman That's how I understood the OP's requirement. Otherwise it would be about filtering the outer map entries to retain only those where all inner maps have 2 entries, which I suspect is not the requirement.

Comment: @ernest_k ..above code is not working for me. Please refer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474763/filtering-through-nested-map-without-disrupting-the-structure-of-outer-map) and help me out if possible