# Filtering through nested map without disrupting the structure of outer map

Tags: java, json, java-8, hashmap

I am trying to write a program to filter hit movies from a json file.
But I am not able to go deep level to get the desired result.

Sample Json contents

```
{
    "Bollywood": {
        "Romance": {
            "hit": false,
            "name": "Prithvi Raj"
        },
        "Action": {
            "hit": true,
            "name": "3 Idiots"
        }


     },

"Hollywood": {
        "Romance": {
            "hit": false,
            "name": "Intimacy"
        },
        "Action": {
            "hit": true,
            "name": "Seven Samurai"
        }


     }


     }
```

Below is the code that I wrote using jackson json parser.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;


public class TestJson
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
    // create object mapper instance
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // convert JSON file to map
    Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("movie.json").toFile(), Map.class);

    
    
    
    
    //map = map.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getKey().equals("Bollywood")).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

map =  map.entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> entry.getValue()
                           .entrySet()
                           .stream()
                           .filter(subEntry -> subEntry.getValue().equals(true))
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 Map.Entry::getValue)))
                        );
    
    
    map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", Value : " + v));
        

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    }
}
```

The above code is giving me below error.

```
TestJson.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
                           .entrySet()
                           ^
  symbol:   method entrySet()
  location: class Object
TestJson.java:49: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K#1,U
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                    ^
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      method getKey in interface Entry<K#2,V> cannot be applied to given types
        required: no arguments
        found:    Object
        reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
  where T,K#1,U,K#2,V are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in method <T,K#1,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T,? extends U>)
    K#1 extends Object declared in method <T,K#1,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T,? extends U>)
    U extends Object declared in method <T,K#1,U>toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K#1>,Function<? super T,? extends U>)
    K#2 extends Object declared in interface Entry
    V extends Object declared in interface Entry
2 errors
```

I want below desired output as a Map. The basic idea is to keep the json structure intact and get movies whose hit value is true. Please help to provide some hint or any workable solution if possible

```
{
    "Bollywood": {
        
        "Action": {
            "hit": true,
            "name": "3 Idiots"
        }


     },

"Hollywood": {
        
        "Action": {
            "hit": true,
            "name": "Seven Samurai"
        }


     }


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Keys* and *Values* of the source map `Map<?, ?>` belong to so-called *unknown type* `?`. Therefore, they can't be treated other than as being of type `java.lang.Object`.

In order to treat the Value as a map, you need to apply casting `((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue())`.

That how it would like:

```
Map<?, ?> result =  map.entrySet().stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue())
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(subEntry -> subEntry.getValue().equals(true))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue
        ))
    ));
```

***Note:** although this code would compile, it's still can fail at Runtime. It would be both **safer** and **cleaner** to use either Jackson's streaming API or data-binding, then dial with a `Map<?,?>` and operate via type casts.*

Comment: ..thanks for the explanation and it compiles now but still I am not able to get my data that is desired. Its showing empty values